# How can I implement Ninject .InSingletonScope() when using Unity IoC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, unity-container

I was using ninject IoC in my application and in particular the following:

```
kernel.Bind<RepositoryFactories>().To<RepositoryFactories>()
   .InSingletonScope();
```

I would like to implement this using the Unity IoC but can someone tell 
me how I can make it the same and also what does it mean "InSingletonScope()" ?
The following works but I am worried that it's not being done correctly because of the Singleton that maybe needs to be specified.

```
container.RegisterType<RepositoryFactories, RepositoryFactories>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unity uses the concept of `LifeTimeManager`'s.. it comes with what is essentially a Singleton `LifeTimeManager` called `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`. You would use it as below:

```
container.RegisterType<RepositoryFactories>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), /* other params */);
```

I'm unsure if you are asking what a Singleton is or not in your question:

> also what does it mean "InSingletonScope()" ?

In the context of an IoC container such as Ninject and Unity, a Singleton is an object that is the same each time you request it. In your example, every time you ask your container to resolve a `RepositoryFactories` object.. it will always be the same object; not a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx) you should use `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`.
Your registration will be:

```
container.RegisterType<RepositoryFactories>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```